# Equivalent of this jQuery code in pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

What would be the equivalent of this piece of code in pure JS (without jQuery)?

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(data[i].url) > -1) {
        slt = data[i].id;
        if ($(slt).length) {
            $(slt).html(data[i].html);
        }
    }
})
```

I tried this [example](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#each) without a success.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(data);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
  alert(el);
});
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: Post your code in a fiddle with a sample `data` object for us to be able to help.

Comment: Are you looking for cross-browser compatibility as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forEach() is an array function which loops over your array elements and provides data element and it's index in callback.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

call() -- called on a and is used to execute a function.

Solution for your question assuming data is some array.

```
data.forEach(function(item,i){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(data[i].url) > -1){
       slt = data[i].id;
       if(slt.length)
       {
            document.getElementById(slt).innerHTML = data[i].html;
       }
    }
});
```